# WOLF (Wordnet Libre du Français, Free French Wordnet) specifications

Tags: wordnet

I am trying to create an interface for  WOLF (Wordnet Libre du Français, Free French Wordnet). The goal is to replicate the AWNDatabaseManger for the Arabic Wordnet (http://www.talp.upc.edu/index.php/technology/resources/multilingual-lexicons-and-machine-translation-resources/multilingual-lexicons/72-awn), but for WOLF.

The problem I am facing is that I cannot find proper data specifications for WOLF (http://alpage.inria.fr/~sagot/wolf-en.html) or WoNeF (which is another French tranlated Wordnet http://wonef.fr/)

For the Arabic Wordnet they have given detailed Data Specifications which can be found at http://globalwordnet.org/arabic-wordnet/awn-data-spec/ 
I am trying to find the same for either WOLF or WoNeF.

Otherwise how do i map the two files?

For example an word and its relation in awn look like:

```
<item itemid="$ajarap_AlS~amog_n1AR" offset="111586059" lexfile="" name="شَجَرَة الصَّمْغ " type="synset" headword="" POS="n" source="" gloss="" authorshipid="80" />

<word wordid="$ajarap__1" value="شَجَرَة الصَّمْغ " synsetid="$ajarap_AlS~amog_n1AR" frequency="" corpus="" authorshipid="11461" />

<link type="has_hyponym" link1="$ajarap_AlS~amog_n1AR" link2="&gt;ukAlibotws_n1AR" authorshipid="35038" />

 <link type="has_hyponym" link1="$ajarap_n1AR" link2="$ajarap_AlS~amog_n1AR" authorshipid="35041" />
```

The word defintion (item) and it's relations (link) are seperated with different attributes.

whereas in WOLF a word and it's relations look like:

```
<SYNSET>
    <ILR type="near_antonym">eng-30-00002098-a</ILR>
    <ILR type="be_in_state">eng-30-05200169-n</ILR>
    <ILR type="be_in_state">eng-30-05616246-n</ILR>
    <ILR type="eng_derivative">eng-30-05200169-n</ILR>
    <ILR type="eng_derivative">eng-30-05616246-n</ILR>
    <ID>eng-30-00001740-a</ID>
    <SYNONYM>
        <LITERAL lnote="2/2:fr.csbgen,fr.csen">comptable</LITERAL>
    </SYNONYM>
    <DEF>(usually followed by `to') having the necessary means or skill or know-how or authority to do something
    </DEF>
    <USAGE>able to swim</USAGE>
    <USAGE>she was able to program her computer</USAGE>
    <USAGE>we were at last able to buy a car</USAGE>
    <USAGE>able to get a grant for the project</USAGE>
    <BCS>3</BCS>
    <POS>a</POS>
</SYNSET>
```

I can make assumptions that awn attribute gloss is equal to wolf tag usage, and awn attribute pos is equal to wolf tag pos.

But the point is I don't want to make assumptions, i am looking for proper documentation from which I can be sure and conclude the mappings between the two files.

Could anyone please point me to the right docs?

Comment: try: compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/ with the http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WOLF database is formatted based on VisDic defined here:
https://nlp.fi.muni.cz/trac/deb2/wiki/WordNetFormat
The XSD is available here: http://deb.fi.muni.cz/debvisdic.xsd

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs, a workaround could be to use the NLTK Python library which integrates some French synsets coming probably from WOLF

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> [synset.lemma_names('fra') for synset in wn.synsets(u'chien'.decode('utf-8'), lang='fra')]
[[u'canis_familiaris', u'chien'], [u'aboyeur', u'chien', u'chienchien', u'clébard', u'toutou'], [u'chien', u'chien_de_chasse'], [u'chien'], [u'chien', u'clic', u'cliquer', u'cliquet'], [u'chien', u'franc', u'hot-dog'], [u'achille', u'chien', u'quignon', u'talon'], [u'chien'], [u'chien']]
```